# In numpy, q1 = p[:] instead of q1 = p, yet p is modified when I modify q1?

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting baffled by how copying a Numpy array works in Python. I start with the following:

```
import numpy as np
p = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.3])
```

Then I try to make "copies" of p using the following three methods:

```
q = p
q1 = p[:]
q2 = p.copy()
```

Now I execute `q1[2] = 0.2`, and then check the values of q, q1, and q2. I was surprised to find that p, q, and q1 all changed to `array([1.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.3])`, while only q2 remains invariant. I have also used `id()` to check the address of all four variables (p, q, q1, q2), and have confirmed that `id(p) = id(q)`, but `id(q1) != id(p)`.

My question is, if `id(q1) != id(p)`, how can a modification of q1 alters p and q? Thanks!

Comment: 2 objects with unique IDs can still access shared memory

Comment: @byxor Thanks for your quick reply! Then what does this ID refer to? I thought id(x) checks the memory location of x, no?

Comment: `[...][:]` makes a (shallow) copy of the list because that's how `list.__getitem__` is defined.  `np.array.__getitem__` is defined differently.

Comment: @Xiao Correct. Although there's nothing to stop 2 objects with separate memory addresses from modifying 1 piece of shared memory. E.g. if 2 instances of a class contain a reference to a list, the instances will have separate IDs but they will both manipulate the same underlying memory (of the list).

Comment: @byxor I see. That's very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) of Numpy states:

> All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array.

Therefore `q1` in your case is a [view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view) of `p` and reflects the changes made to `p`.

Comment: What I found confusing is that whether the object is an array or a view the type function returns type=<class 'numpy.ndarray'> in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are using a simple slicing operation, numpy will use a shared memory view of the resulting slice of the array.  In this case it is the entire array.  They are referenced by different python objects, but the underlying numpy array is the same.  `q1` is just a view into the same array that `p` is referencing.

You can check this using `np.shared_memory`.

```py
import numpy as np
p = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.3])

q1 = p[:]

np.shares_memory(p, q1)
# returns:
True
```

This is even true when the slice is not of the entire array.  Such as:

```py
p = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.3])

q2 = p[1::2]
print(q2)
#prints:
[0.  0.3]

# setting a value of q2 changes p
q2[0] = 10.0
p
# returns:
array([ 1. , 10. ,  1. ,  0.3])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So in order to create a truly independent copy of p, I should use p.copy() then?

Comment: Yes. That is the best method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! A follow-up question: In terms of making an independent copy of p (so that changes to q2 will not affect p), is q2 = p.copy() enough? Do I ever need q2 = p.deepcopy() to make sure q2 is independent of p?

Comment: Copy should be enough unless it is a numpy array of nested python objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's very helpful for me:)